# Filtering columns based on conditions related to IDs

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following `data.frame`

```
df = data.frame(plot = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                tree = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
                            "3", "4", "7", "7"),
                trunk = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", 
                             "1", "1", "1", "2"),
                name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                         "B", "C", "A", "A"),
                time_1 = c("alive", "alive", "dead", "dead",
                           "alive", "alive",
                           "alive",
                           "alive",
                           "dead", "dead"),
                time_2 = c("dead", "alive", "dead", "dead",
                             "dead", "dead",
                             "dead",
                             "dead",
                             "dead", "dead"))
```

To rapidly explain the context, I have for each `plot` a number of `tree` and each `tree` can have a single `trunk` or multiples `trunk`. What I'm trying to do is keep **only** `tree` that have `time_1 == "alive"` and `time_2 == "dead"`. **A `tree` can have multiple "dead" `trunk`, but if a single `trunk` is alive, then I consider the `tree` to be "alive".**

So, the first thing I did was add some identifiers for each `tree` and `trunk`:

```
#Adding an ID for each trunk in each plot
df$trunk_id <- paste(df$plot, "_",
                   df$tree, "_",
                   df$trunk,
                   sep = "")

#Adding an ID for each tree in each plot  
df$tree_id <- paste(df$plot, "_",
                    df$tree,
                    sep = "")
```

Then, I was filtering only cases where the `time_1 == "alive"` and `time_2 == "dead"`.

```
df2 <- df %>% filter(time_1 == "alive" & time_2 == "dead")
```

However, I noticed that this would not return exactly what I wanted. For example, looking at `df` when compared to `df2`, I know for a fact that I don't want `plot == 1` and `tree_id == "1_1"` because at least one of the `trunk` is "alive" (see bold above). And filtering like that would not remove these cases.

What type of condition should I add to consider the entirety of the `time_1` when related to each `tree` with multiple `trunk`?

My ideal output would be these IDs, so I'd be able to filter out what is irrelevant

```
output <- c("1_2", "2_3", "2_4")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding `all()` in your condition, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(plot, tree) %>% 
 filter(all(time_1 == 'alive') & all(time_2 == 'dead'))

# A tibble: 4 × 6
# Groups:   plot, tree [3]
   plot tree  trunk name  time_1 time_2
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1     1 2     1     A     alive  dead  
2     1 2     2     A     alive  dead  
3     2 3     1     B     alive  dead  
4     2 4     1     C     alive  dead
```

Comment: I think this does the job. I was doing it more manually and got into the same results as before (using my whole data set). So, I'm not doing anything wrong, at least. But your answer is better than what I was doing anyway, more simplified. Thanks!